# Amazon (AWS) zagent is it a malware / remote?

Tags: malware, remote, amazon-web-services, netstat

i ran netstat command and found some amazon tcp connections that i don't know

```
zagent1644.h-cdn.com
142.44.212.29

zagent1642.h-cdn.com
145.239.8.193

zagent859.h-cdn.com
217.182.138.56

zagent1678.h-cdn.com
54.37.85.231
```

could they be a like an api that sends commands from a RAT to the spyware inside my computer ?
do you have any idea about them ?

Comment: In what sense do you believe these are "amazon" TCP connections?  Additionally, where do you see this?  Is this a personal computer or a server?

Comment: Look up the IP addresses via http://whois.arin.net/ui/ and reach out to point of contact if you want as well.

Comment: it is my personal computer and i know amazon owns them because the domain h-cdn is registred to amazon, some say that a malware remote can be hosted in amazon so  it doesn't get caught

Answer (score 2):

None of this makes any sense. Let's start from the beginning.

Whois h-cdn.com?

```
$ whois h-cdn.com
   Domain Name: H-CDN.COM
   Registry Domain ID: 1941013588_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.godaddy.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
   Updated Date: 2017-05-11T05:47:51Z
   Creation Date: 2015-06-22T13:21:45Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2019-06-22T13:21:45Z
   Registrar: GoDaddy.com, LLC
   Registrar IANA ID: 146
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@godaddy.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: 480-624-2505
   Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
   Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
   Name Server: NS-1336.AWSDNS-39.ORG
   Name Server: NS-1696.AWSDNS-20.CO.UK
   Name Server: NS-421.AWSDNS-52.COM
   Name Server: NS-608.AWSDNS-12.NET
```

It looks like this domain is served from Amazon nameservers, but there is no indication Amazon is the registrant. The fact that GoDaddy is the registrar is suspicious; they ask no questions about customer identity and are terrible about responding to abuse complaints so they're popular among fraudsters and malware authors.

All four of those IPs listed are assigned to OVH, similar to Amazon, but different in that they do not seem to have any legitimate business these days beyond providing infrastructure for botnets, crawlers/scrapers, ad networks and other shadiness. So there's that as well.

What else I've seen of h-cdn is a lot of TCP traffic bound for subdomains of `h-cdn.com` on port 443 with dst IPs assigned to Leaseweb, another internet paragon of integrity and virtue.

Our firewall shoots down all this traffic on sight so I don't have any metrics. Amazon has nothing to do with this, and none of the rest of the infrastructure involved here has a clean history but there is no evidence we're looking at malware or RATs; given the context in which I see similar traffic surrounding these events my guess is we're dealing with an ad network using websockets to keep connections open (to spy/"perform behavioral analytics" on users), hence why you're seeing it in netstat.